# How to drop duplicated column names in nested tibbles before unnesting

Tags: r, tidyr, unnest

I have a tibble with a column containing (nested) tibbles. The nested tibbles have duplicated data (same names, same values):

```
df <- tibble(id = 1:2, data = list(tibble(id = 1, var1 = "a", var2 = "b"), tibble(id = 2, var1 = "c", var2 = "d")))

df

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#      id data            
#   <int> <list>          
# 1     1 <tibble [1 x 3]>
# 2     2 <tibble [1 x 3]>
```

Calling `df %>% unnest(data)` results in

> `Error: Names must be unique.`.

I would like to write a function that drops these columns beforehand but don't know how. My goal is to be run to use something along the lines of:

```
df %>% 
  drop_duplicated_cols(data) %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

Which would result in:

```
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>      id var1  var2 
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 a     b    
#> 2     2 c     d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `unnest_longer`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  unnest_longer(data)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id data$id $var1 $var2
  <int>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1       1 a     b    
2     2       2 c     d
```

---

If you want to truly convert the tibble column, you can also use:

```
df %>%
  left_join(reduce(df$data, bind_rows), by = "id")
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
     id data             var1  var2 
  <dbl> <list>           <chr> <chr>
1     1 <tibble [1 x 3]> a     b    
2     2 <tibble [1 x 3]> c     d
```

And from there you can e.g. unselect the data column.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `names_repair` argument in `unnest`.  By default, it is `"check_unique"` and this causes the error.  If we change it to another option i.e. "unique", it will make the columns that are duplicated with `..` followed by some digits, then we use `select` to get the columns not duplicated

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    unnest(data, names_repair = "unique") %>%
    select(names(.)[!duplicated(str_remove(names(.), "\\.+.*"))]) %>%
    rename_with(~ str_remove(., "\\.+.*"), contains(".."))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id var1  var2 
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     b    
2     2 c     d
```

---

Or another option to avoid the warnings is to remove the duplicate columns within the `list` by looping with `map`

```
library(purrr)
out <- df %>% 
   mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% 
            select(-any_of(names(df))))) %>%
   unnest(data)
out
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id var1  var2 
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     b    
2     2 c     d    
> str(out)
tibble [2 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ id  : int [1:2] 1 2
 $ var1: chr [1:2] "a" "c"
 $ var2: chr [1:2] "b" "d"
```

NOTE: Both solutions give the expected output as in the OP's post along with the structure

Answer (score 0):

Combine the `df$data` rows together and join with the original dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df %>% select(-data), bind_rows(df$data), by = 'id')

#     id var1  var2 
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 a     b    
#2     2 c     d
```